# fillna(0) does not change null values to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a leetcode question and somehow the fillna(0) fails to convert null values to 0. Does anyone know why this is the case? Thank you so much!!

```
import pandas as pd

def average_selling_price(prices: pd.DataFrame, units_sold: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    merged_df = units_sold.merge(prices, on = 'product_id', how = 'outer')
    filtered_df = merged_df[((merged_df['purchase_date'] >= merged_df['start_date']) & (merged_df['purchase_date'] <= merged_df['end_date'])) | (merged_df['purchase_date'].isnull())]
    calculated_df = filtered_df.copy(deep = True)[['product_id', 'units', 'price']]
    calculated_df['sum_product'] = calculated_df['units'] * calculated_df['price']
    pivoted_df = calculated_df.groupby('product_id').agg({'sum_product': 'sum', 'units': 'sum'}).reset_index()
    pivoted_df['average_price'] = round(pivoted_df['sum_product'] / pivoted_df['units'], 2)
    pivoted_df = pivoted_df[['product_id', 'average_price']]
    return pivoted_df .fillna(0)
```

Details of the failed test case:

[image]

Here's a breakdown of my code:

1. merged_df: The function begins by merging the units_sold dataframe with the prices dataframe on the product_id column using an outer join.
2. filtered_df: This dataframe filters rows from the merged dataframe based on two conditions:
   a). Either the purchase_date falls between the start_date and end_date.
   b). Or, the purchase_date is null (this step intentionally retains rows where purchase_date is null).
3. calculated_df: This dataframe is derived from the filtered dataframe by selecting only three columns ('product_id', 'units', 'price'). The new column sum_product is added which is the product of 'units' and 'price'.
4. pivoted_df: This dataframe is generated by grouping the previous dataframe by product_id and calculating the sum of 'sum_product' and 'units' for each product. Then, the average_price column is calculated by dividing sum_product by units and rounding to two decimal places.
5. Finally, return pivoted_df and fill all null values with 0.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
data = {'product_id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
        'purchase_date': ['2019-02-25', '2019-03-01', '2019-02-10', '2019-03-22'],
        'units': [100, 15, 200, 30]}
units_sold = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'product_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'start_date': ['2019-02-17', '2019-03-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-21', '2019-02-21'],
        'end_date': ['2019-02-28', '2019-03-22', '2019-02-20', '2019-03-31', '2019-03-31'],
        'price': [5, 20, 15, 30, 30]}
prices = pd.DataFrame(data)

# units_sold
   product_id purchase_date  units
0           1    2019-02-25    100
1           1    2019-03-01     15
2           2    2019-02-10    200
3           2    2019-03-22     30

# prices
   product_id start_date   end_date  price
0           1 2019-02-17 2019-02-28      5
1           1 2019-03-01 2019-03-22     20
2           2 2019-02-01 2019-02-20     15
3           2 2019-02-21 2019-03-31     30
4           3 2019-02-21 2019-03-31     30
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem must be in how this function is called and how the returned value is handled, which you have not shown us.

Comment: please see the "details of the failed test case" for test case screenshot result

Comment: null is a string and not np.nan.  `df_pivoted.mask(df_pivoted.eq('null')).fillna(0)`

Comment: Thanks Scott@ScottBoston for the suggestion really appreciate it! Tried the code but still has the same error hummm.

Comment: Your code works well for me. There is no NaN at the end. What is your version of Pandas?

Comment: It works fine for me too.

Comment: @OCa. I provided the data, not the OP. I didn't delete the picture because it contains the error.

Comment: @Corralien nice, thank you

Comment: There's a space in your return line: return pivoted_df .fillna(0) between df and .fillna. Could that be causing a problem?